# Transactions without receiver_address

Tags: transaction, address

I am trying to figure out transactions without receiver address or same receiver and sender address .
What do these transactions mean ? I also see a deposit in the later part of the transaction. Can someone break the transactions down for me . Sharing some sample transaction hashes .

56e51e0766b072a94bfe6d02218ef39d25634c9493b0c93b2e1a1a7a0a3fc981
327ece1ac5cee03c3def2fd831aec1ec4c28a113a0ef0e87af1bf9e504f2b098
0fbeb9d4a30b8adf611669a9bdbda20c8a7cefa37bfb4e1ac1d374d19566c912
2cfd2cede25959b1493e7e438fde71f020675ab4b7dbfe3f4f4e6108d213b553

Answer (score 2):

The first transaction looks like it is intended to "defragment" two utxos into one, no idea why...

The other transactions are stake pool registration transactions. The pool deposit of 500 Ada is being submitted in these transactions.

The Cardano Blockchain Explorer clearly mentions this 500 Ada as a deposit. View your second transaction [here](https://explorer.cardano.org/en/transaction?id=327ece1ac5cee03c3def2fd831aec1ec4c28a113a0ef0e87af1bf9e504f2b098)

In case you're wondering where the 500 Ada goes to, no... it doesn't go to the treasury... instead it seems to be recorded on the ledger itself as a deposit. This can be returned later on to the stake pool if and when it is deregistered. Read more [here](https://forum.cardano.org/t/where-does-the-500-ada-registration-deposit-go/64737/11)

To find out more about this process, refer to the [corresponding documentation](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/stake-pool-course/handbook/register-stake-pool-metadata)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey thank you for the info . This helps a lot .

Comment: if you found the answer useful, please consider upvoting the answer as useful and marking it as the solution.